# Linebreak in table on github pages = undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I know it's a year later, but I am struggling with this again.

Github proper renders this:

`| Foo     | Bar | Quux  |
|---------|-----|-------|
| X       | v1  |       |
| Y       | v2  | * note1<br> * note2 |`

But gh-pages/jekyll gives me:

`` Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Markdown encountered an error while converting 'docs/deprecation-policy.md':
                    undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
jekyll 3.3.1 | Error:  undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass ``

I don't know anything about jekyll or ruby, really, and I am at a loss.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Do you have a repository url ?

Comment: Did you find any way to add a br? A colleague has had the same problem and he finally has removed the br

Comment: I gave up on gh-pages

Answer (score 0):

try to add an empty string `"  "` or `&nbsp;` in the void cell :

```
| Foo     | Bar | Quux  |
|---------|-----|-------|
| X       | v1  | "  "  |
| Y       | v2  | * note1<br> * note2 |
```